# Аналог Object.Equals на C++?

Tags: c++

Нужно сравнить два объекта в шаблонном методе. 
В *C#* я бы написал:

```
public static bool Compare<T>(T a, T b)
{
    return a.Equals(b);
}
```

Можно ли что-то подобное провернуть в *C++*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В C++ для сравнения объектов активно используется оператор == (может быть даже
перегруженный). Но нужно учесть, что строки в стиле Си таким образом
сравнивать не стоит, и поэтому для этого случая можно написать отдельную
перегрузку.

```
template <typename T>
bool Compare(const& T a, const& T b)
{
    return a == b;
}
bool Compare(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    return !std::strcmp(a, b);
}
```

Comment: А если захочется сравнивать именно указатели на char? Или сравнить объекты по указателям на них? ТЗ нечёткое.